# ERROR : 404 Page not found in codeigniter on centos7

Tags: codeigniter, centos7

My codeigniter project is successfully running on windows but showed error in centos7

```
    ERROR : 404 Page not found
The page your are requested was not found
```

Here is my .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|img|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Can't figure out....please help.....

Comment: do you use htaccess?

Comment: yes i use htaccess

Comment: paste it here, it's probably cause of tour problem

Comment: @Mahdi Majidzadeh I edited my question for your better understanding

Comment: [Since you're on Centos, make sure it's not selinux blocking you](http://serverfault.com/questions/642353/selinux-interfering-with-apache-php). You can test it by temporarily turning it off with `setenforce 0`.

Comment: Would you post your link?

Comment: It's not in live @Brad

Answer (score 0):

use this snippet for `htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```